# How to use compress a repetitive command into one when only one parameter is changing?

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to use `defaults write` to assign values to multiples keys. The commands that look like:

```
defaults write key1 val
defaults write key2 val
defaults write key3 val
```

I would like to do this in one shot without using `&&` between commands. I tried to use:

```
defaults write {key1,key2,key3} val
```

But this doesn't work. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

`{a,b}c` expands to `ac bc`. but `a {b,c}` to `a b c`. Either pipe the keys to `xargs` if available on osx or use bash's `for` cycle.

Comment: So.. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: It expands to `defaults write key1 key2 key3 val`.